# How to generate headings from within Vue Components in Vuepress

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

Is there a way to generate the same heading and link in sidevar, from within a vue component as you would if using normal markdown headings?

I have a Vue component inside Vuepress, that generates a list of links, but I want it to generate linked headings as well, so I can link to it easily when answering someone's question.

I know the link in the Heading uses a router-link, but I cant want to have name collision detection as well.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue: I want to define a Vue Component in VuePress that adds a heading to toc & sidebar. Did you find a solution?

Comment: See github issues [#1423](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/1423) and [#2002](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/2002)